# Calling method from MVC view does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am familiar with C# / .net, but pretty new with .net mvc and razor things,
what I am trying to do is, that I want to call a method in a controller from the view to render the string path as binary,
so i do this in the view :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ReadFile", "FLK",  new { path = Model.Pict })" />
```

and this in the controller :

```
public void ReadFile(string path)
{
    Response.ContentType = "image";
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
}
```

but when I put a debug point in the controller, my debug point never trigerred, any clue? Need some advice thank you.

Comment: `Url.Action` generates a link to specified view in mvc application - it doesn't hit an action. Have you check wheter link is generated properyl (inside html)?

Comment: @pwas yes, the link is generated properly, then as u mentioned, do u have any advise to make my link hit an action / being called. usually i do this trick in normal web form, and it works, but no luck with MVC.

Comment: It's Html.Action, not Url.Action. Url.Action generates the link and  Html.Action actually calls the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReadFile()` method in the controller should be something like this -

```
public ActionResult ReadFile(string path)
{
    byte[] imgBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(imgBytes, "image/png"); 
}
```

Here, your action method reads the image file into a byte array and then uses File() method of the ActionResult base class to send the contents to the caller.

So you can use it in your View like this -

```
<img src='@Url.Action("ReadFile", new { path = Model.Pict }))'/>
```

Comment: +1 thx, my method is called now, actually i just need to change url to html, i tried ur and it worked to, but now the problem is when my method being called it caused this error, Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Comment: Send image as Base64String, that would display the image. then src should looks like this:   src="data:image/jpeg;base64,am"

Comment: @HendraLim: Is your view is Partialview or normail view ?? If possible then post the code of your view...

Comment: it's a normal view, i found a solution here http://forums.asp.net/t/1933667.aspx?OutputStream+is+not+available+when+a+custom+TextWriter+is+used

Comment: @HendraLim: That's great...So they specify only action in the Url.Action. That's the difference in their answer and my answer, right ??

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method should look like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ReadFile(string path)
{

    return new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(path)), "image");
}
```

The code in view is ok. But make sure the path to image is like "~\Images\Test.png"; Now the break point in the controller will be hit. It will be hit when the page is loaded in the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileContentResult getImage(int id)
{
    byte[] imgBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    if (imgBytes!= null)
    {
        return new FileContentResult(imgBytes, "image/jpeg");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On Razor

```
<img src="@Html.Action("ReadFile", "FLK", new { path = Model.Pict })" />
```